# To create a one-dimensional array which contains, in order, the array indices used to access a number in the given variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

//I am trying to learn/understand to create a one-dimensional array which contains, in exact order, the array indices used to access a given number within a multi dimensional array

```
var multiDimensionalArray = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9, [10, 11, 12, [13, 14, [15]]]]]];
```

// to access 15...

```
fifteen = multiDimensionalArray[3][3][3][3][2][0];
```

// Define the variable 'indexArray' here:

```
indexArray = fifteen.join();
```

//join method does not work for me. I have tried concat, slice, indexOf methods. Can't seem to be able to find the solution for this part. HELP!

// This will log your variables to the console

```
console.log(fifteen); //15
```

console.log(indexArray); //[3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 0]

Comment: What you are looking for a is a findIndex that works for multi-dimensional arrays. If your structure is always following a certain pattern it might make more sense to just devide e.g. 15 by in this case 3 (subtract 1) and just fill an array with 3s and the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function :

```js
var multiDimensionalArray = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9, [10, 11, 12, [13, 14, [15]]]]]];


const getIndex = (arr, num) => {
  const path = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      path.push(i);
      path.push(getIndex(arr[i], num));
      break;
    }
    if (arr[i] === num) {
      path.push(i);
      break;
    }
  }

  return path.flat();
};

const indexArray = getIndex(multiDimensionalArray, 15);
console.log(indexArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach with a recursive function:

```js
var multiDimensionalArray = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9, [10, 11, 12, [13, 14, [15]]]]]];

const find = (node, needle) => {
  const index = node.indexOf(needle);
  const nextIndex = node.findIndex(Array.isArray);
  return [].concat(...
    (index !== -1)
      ? [index]
      : [nextIndex, find(node[nextIndex], needle)]
  );

};

const result = find(multiDimensionalArray, 15);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach and return either an empty array fro a not found value or the indices.

```js
function getIndices(array, value) {
    var subIndices = [],
        index = array.findIndex(v => v === value || Array.isArray(v) && (subIndices = getIndices(v, value)).length);
    return index === -1
        ? []
        : [index, ...subIndices];
}


var array = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6, [7, 8, 9, [10, 11, 12, [13, 14, [15]]]]]]

console.log(getIndices(array, 15));
console.log(getIndices(array, 42));
```